# Nodemailer Error that may be result of port error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nodemailer

I'm using Nodemailer and I get an error that I can't seem to solve. Some sites say it's my firewall blocking ports, I opened the ports and used different ports, didn't solve much.

Below are logs of the errors Nodemailer emitted.

```
[2020-10-07 03:38:23] DEBUG Creating transport: nodemailer (6.4.13; +https://nodemailer.com/; SMTP/6.4.13[client:6.4.13])
[2020-10-07 03:38:23] DEBUG Sending mail using SMTP/6.4.13[client:6.4.13]
[2020-10-07 03:38:23] DEBUG [TNYM4ZexJbo] Resolved smtp.mailtrap.io as 34.224.73.100 [cache miss]
[2020-10-07 03:38:44] ERROR [TNYM4ZexJbo] connect EACCES 34.224.73.100:25
[2020-10-07 03:38:44] DEBUG [TNYM4ZexJbo] Closing connection to the server using "destroy"
[2020-10-07 03:38:44] ERROR Send Error: connect EACCES 34.224.73.100:25
```